# Working as a freelancer at an office in the UK

Tags: uk

I'd like to start working at an office to limit procrastination and give fresh air to my wife who's a housewife.

Among you guys are there some who work in an office outside? How much do you pay?

Comment: This post slipped through the cracks due to the New Year, so I apologize. In general, we're looking for questions about a real, actual problem you're facing. Real problems have plenty of detail to describe what it is you're looking at. Me telling you I pay $50 for a tiny office is useless to you if you need a 2,000 square foot space. We can see that in many of the answers there are no specifics. If you [edit] this with more details about exactly what you need, I think we might be able to make this work. See [ask] for more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

There are several options to get desk space to work at.

There are:

- serviced offices (little private offices incl most bills*)
  [More privacy, higher cost, less of a community]
- coworking spaces (normally open plan spaces incl bills)
  [Less Privacy, lower cost, most community]
- individual desks in current businesses
  [No privacy, lower cost, source of income possible]

each are great for different stages and types of freelancers/entrepreneurs.

*But please please please be careful of hidden fees like paying for internet (yes in this day and age it still happens)

We work with quite a few desk space providers at [www.deskand.co](http://deskand.co) who guarantee transparency, and if we don't have a host partner in your area let me know and I'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 1):

It's very common to have a separate office space purely for working; In the UK, you can get tax breaks for the costs of doing so (when helps to keep costs at a reasonable amount).

For many people, it can help with motivation; If you work from home at your usual home computer, you'll have a chance of lapsing into a cycle of procrastination easier.

It also helps make a clear division between your work and home life.

As for pricing, this is wildly dependent on where you live (and how many successful businesses are working in the area), but try to look for buildings made exclusively for office space: a big block of offices of varying sizes. The rent for these offices are determined by how big they are, in square feet.

In the Northeast of the UK, for example, a small office (~100sq ft) is usually around £240-320/month excluding VAT and including all utilities. If you have a business, you can claim tax breaks from VAT as well.

Another choice is to create a home office in another part of your house, and have your wife understand that work time is when you're in that room.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you may be able to rent a desk, either in a dedicated co-working space or from a company with excess space. As per @Santa's answer the price will vary depending on where you are — the ones I've looked at in my area (Central Scotland) are about half the price of a dedicated office, generally <£200 a month, and that will usually include utilities.